# Chrome JetBrains plugin wont be recognized by WebStorm 6.0

Tags: plugins, ide, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm

I've tried to solve this for so long now. I've installed the plugin from the Chrome store but the plugin button in the browser is grayed out and says "**Not connected**" on hover. When I debug in WS I get this popup:

[image]

I've seen the help section on JB site but the help there is utterly poor, and doesn't even mention the problem with the plugin and the IDE not recognizing eachother.

I've looked over other posts here with similar problems, though usually it revolved around LiveEditing, and I haven't found any help there for my problem.

Can someone please give me a sequence of steps to perform to check where the problem is with the syncing between the IDE and the Chrome plugin?

**EDIT :**

The JB console is empty when I open it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Right click to JetBrains chrome extension
- Select "Options"
- Set Host: 127.0.0.1
- Set Port: 63343
- Click "Apply"

You're ready to go

Answer (score 0):

please, check what is written in extension console (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/LiveEdit, How do I know what's wrong?)
The console contents along with your idea.log (Help/Reveal log) would be helpful

Comment: Thanks, the console is empty. I don't know if I need to select something in the modal or if I can refresh it somehow. I'm not sure where I get the log, there is no Help > Reveal log either in Chrome or in WS.

Comment: Do you have Chrome Developer Tools opened? You can't use JetBrains Chrome extension with it - see the [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1832)

Comment: there is no Help > Reveal log either in Chrome or in WS: sorry, the action is now called Help/Show Log in Explorer (Finder, etc. depending on your OS)